# Best Time Complexity for Sorted 2D Array Search in Java

Tags: java

So I have the following code to search a sorted 2D array for a target number, but I am not sure if this is the best time complexity as in terms of Big-Oh, I read that there is a way to do in O(N), but I am not sure if my algorithm is efficient enough.

```
public class Search2DArray {

public static int search(int[][] arrayA, int number, int target) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = number - 1;
    while (i < number && j >= 0) {
        if (arrayA[i][j] == target) {
            System.out.printf("\n Found at %d, %d", i, j);
            return 1;
        }
        if (arrayA[i][j] > target) {
            j--;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("\n Element not found");
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int arrayA[][] = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, 
                   {5, 6, 7, 8}, 
                   {9, 10, 11, 12}};
    search(arrayA, 3, 11);
}
}
```

Comment: It's still binary search; just binary search the beginnings of each row and then binary search the row you found in the first binary search.

Comment: What is the `number` parameter supposed to do?

Comment: @LouisWasserman is correct, with perhaps the minor addition to check both the beginning and end of a row during your outer binary search, then as mentioned binary search the matching row.  I think this will make the logic easier since you know immediately whether you have found the correct row or not without any backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

well if your 2D array is sorted you can simply reduce the rows to select and run binary search on the rows that you think that contains the target number this may reduce the complexity even better may be something in order of LOG